# Prove that $\mathrm{ord}(a^d)=\mathrm{ord}(a)/d$ when $d$ divides $\mathrm{ord}(a)$

Tags: group-theory

Given is that $a∈ℤ_n^*$ and $d|ord(a)$.

I need to show that $ord(a^d)= ord(a)/d$.

I started with the following:

$ord(a^d) = e$, such that $(a^d)^e\equiv 1\pmod n$

$ord(a)/d =f/d$ where $ord(a)=f$, such that $a^f\equiv 1\pmod n$

Now I want to prove that $e=f/d$.

I have tried multiplying and dividing the formulas, but I am not able to prove it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\text{ord}(a)$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^{\text{ord}(a)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$; $\frac{\text{ord}(a)}{d}$ is the smallest positive real number such that $\left(a^{d}\right)^{\frac{\text{ord}(a)}{d}}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ (and such that $d\cdot \frac{\text{ord}(a)}{d}$ is a positive integer), but $d\mid \text{ord}(a)$, so $\frac{\text{ord}(a)}{d}$ is a positive integer, so $\frac{\text{ord}(a)}{d}=\text{ord}\left(a^d\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using number theory. Since $ord(a)$ is the smallest positive power of $a$ satisfying $a^{ord(a)}\equiv 1$ then $(a^d)^{(ord(a)/d)}\equiv 1$ and it is the smallest such element.